# How to Place an "If" before a vlookup?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm familiar with IF functions and vlookups but not how to use them together. In my example I want to check if column D is marked as "T". If it is then I want to do a vlookup based on another column (specifically column K would reference another tab to do a vlookup). If it isn't a T, I'd like it to show as blank.

To summarize, I only want the vlookup function to happen IF another column is filled with the letter "T".

I've tried looking this up a lot and seen answers that seem that they should work but then they don't. Lots of data on multiple vlookup formulas but this is IF + vlookup. I'm open to fancy QUERY ideas but then I'd need a bit more help.

Comment: It is always difficult to try to write or suggest formulas without specifics, as formulas are based on specifics. While *you* know your spreadsheet, keep in mind that we don't. We don't know your setup, data, data types, ranges, international locale (which affect formula setup), whether you are using array formulas or drag-down formulas, etc. I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it) and then specifically note what you are trying to do, where, and what the expect result should be (for at least a few rows).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but there is too much private information on the spreadsheet for it to be shared publicly. I wasn't expecting an exact formula but perhaps information on can this be done? And if there is an IF/Vlookup option, how in general does it work. And finally, might there be a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? Thanks again

Comment: I suggest that you make a copy of the spreadsheet, delete all but 10 rows of data, replace any sensitive information in those remaining rows with realistic dummy data, and share a link to that copy. Always keep in mind that this is a free forum run by volunteers; so you may need to put in a little extra time in order to get the help you seek. But creating such a spreadsheet copy should not take more than perhaps 10 minutes.

Comment: That is an excellent idea. I will do it. Thank you Erik

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.